# Selenium WebDriver exception when multiple processes run in parallel

Tags: c#, sockets, selenium, exception, parallel-processing

I have a process, using Selenium Web driver for Firefox, for automatic look up for information on one specific site. Due to the volume of the data being looked up, I am running in parallel several copies of this process. Sometimes they are ok, sometimes I get an exception, which I do not understand the cause for. The Process is written in C#, runs on Windows. Each process creates its own instance of Selenium, FF web driver, I see each process has a separate FireFox process. No multi-treading (inside one process). I do not understand what exactly is the issue. Could not find any documentation that could tell me more.
If anyone has an idea, I'd appreciate any info/suggestions

The exception is:

"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted 127.0.0.1:7056"

I can not see what can be trying to make more  than one "usage" of the socket address in one given process. And from the logs I see that the different processes use different ports ( the "7056" above is a different number in each process).

Thank you in advace

Comment: Just to add: I am not running Selenium server; just using the Selenium WebDriver dlls (for C#)

Comment: Another variation:  "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7056/hub/session/ea22aa52-fb91-45d1-adf7-de580c800618/element/%7B1fd9957a-0ae7-4855-ae28-ad48de5f76c8%7D/text. The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: .....  "     (the rest is as in the first example; too long for the chars limit here)

Comment: Webdriver works by running a daemon process which the selenium programs will talk to via http. Anyway, if you are doing this in high parallel what happens is that you are sometimes occasionally running out of possible connections. The reason is that even though you've closed the connection, the OS keeps that connection "locked" for a few minutes. see this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgorti/2005/09/18/only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted/ Now, probably the easiest solution for you is to slow down or reduce the parallelization.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this and found a pretty interesting article about fine tuning your network settings.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgorti/2005/09/18/only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted/

so pretty much if you run a high degree of parallelism in your tests with not enough ports open and a high timeout you will run out of sockets and this will happen. either increase the ports, reduce the wait time and check what can be leaving your instances hanging.

Comment: As suggested here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4162#issuecomment-501703876 , I dared to try the 4 alpha version (currently 07), it works for me.